# Do I have to remove features with pairwise correlation even if I am doing a regularized logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic-regression, regularization, lasso

Normally we would remove features that have high pairwise correlation with another feature before performing regression. But is this step necessary if I am applying L2 regularized logistic regression (since the regularization algorithm would shrink the "irrelevant" feature coefficients to zero anyway)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the L1 regularization will shrink the irrelevant feature coefficients to zero and hence it doesn't require feature selection. In fact it **IS** a commonly used feature selection technique. So basically you are performing feature selection!!

Comment: Do you perhaps mean $L1$ (LASSO) regression? LASSO can (and often does) shrink coefficients to zero (not quite the same as feature selection...run a regression on just the "surviving" features and compare the coefficient estimates), but ridge regression would not be expected to shrink all the way to zero.

Comment: @Dave My bad! Probably a typo. Corrected.